# Why is that static variable values are getting changed in Main method?

Tags: java

I have written a simple program like below which is confusing me:

```
    package BasePackage;

public class ParentClass {
    static int i=15;
    double f=4.5;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParentClass obj1= new ParentClass();
        obj1.i=10;
        obj1.printvalue();
        System.out.println("The value of i is " +i);

    }
    public void printvalue()
    {
        ParentClass obj1= new ParentClass();
        int i =30;
        obj1.i=25;
        System.out.println("The value of i in the method is " +i);
    }

}
```

I am getting an output like The value of i in the method is 30 and the value of i is 25. My question is the static value of i at class level i.e 15 should be printed as the static value should not be changed. Also i am changing the value of i =25 in the method, so why is it not getting printed instead of 30?

Comment: `i` is not the same as `obj1.i`.

Comment: Your local declaration of `int i` is shadowing the static member within the `printValue` method, so the `i` in the `s.o.println` call is the *local* `i`, not the static `i` from the class.

Comment: This is really unacceptable that somebody down voted the question without even trying to comprehend that somebody might have confusion regarding this. Also if somebody is doing it ,can you please specify why you are doing so? Things which might seem mundane to you, it may not be for all..So i do hope that  i will get some clarification so as to why somebody did this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is the static value of i at class level i.e 15 should be printed as the static value should not be changed.

When a variable is static, only one instance of that variable exists across all objects of the same class.  So when you call `obj1.i = 25`, you're changing `i` for *all* instances of your class, *including the one you're currently in*.

This might be more clear if we step through the code and see what it's doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParentClass obj1= new ParentClass();

    // Set i for ALL ParentClass instances to 10
    obj1.i=10; 

    // See below.  When you come back from this method, ParentClass.i will be 25
    obj1.printvalue(); 

    // Print the value of i that was set in printValue(), which is 25
    System.out.println("The value of i is " +i); /
}

public void printvalue() {
    ParentClass obj1= new ParentClass(); 

    // Create a new local variable that shadows ParentClass.i
    // For the rest of this method, i refers to this variable, and not ParentClass.i
    int i =30; 

    // Set i for ALL ParentClass instances to 25 (not the i you created above)
    obj1.i=25; 

    // Print the local i that you set to 30, and not the static i on ParentClass
    System.out.println("The value of i in the method is " +i); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`int i` is a local variable that only exists in the scope of `printvalue()` (This method should be named `printValue()`). You initialize your local variable `i` to 30.

`obj1.i=25` is the *static* `i` field in the Object `obj1`. When you instantiate `obj` with `ParentClass obj1= new ParentClass();`, you are creating an instance of `ParentClass` with a static `i` field value of 10. You then change the value of `obj1.i` to 25.

This is unrelated to the local variable `int i`.

Answer (score 1):

You have different variables (in different scopes) that are both called `i`:

- a static variable of type primitive integer: `static int i=15;`
- a local variable of type primitive integer (only visible in scope of it's owning method `printvalue()`: `int i =30;`

You can access static variables from a non-static context, but not instance variables from a static context.

In your `printvalue()` method you set local var `i` to value 30  and afterwards set a new value (25) for static variable `i`. Because both share the same variable name the static var `i` is "shadowed" by it's local counterpart... that's the reason why the output it 30 and not 25.

You also might have a look at this: https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java